# yeoman this.copyTpl not working

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

when i try to copy files with `this.fs.copyTpl` nothing is copied, but if use `this.fs.copy` work as expected, but i need `this.fs.copyTpl` to replace some vars. i saw the oficial documentation on yeoman and looking on google but nothing that help me.
here the block of code

```
this.fs.copyTpl(
  this.templatePath('_bower.json'),
  this.destinationPath(projectPath +'/bower.json'),{
    projectName: this.project_name 
  }
 );
```

thanks for help

Comment: Any chance the template logic is broken and throws? Try updating yeoman-generator to `^0.23.0`, error handling have been improved with this release.

Comment: thanks @SimonBoudrias, i update yeoman-generator to ^0.23.3 and work well, but why underscore functions on my templates not working ?

Comment: There's no default functions inside templates. If you want to use underscore in your templates, then you need to pase `_` as a template value.

Comment: i can't understand your response...in older version of yeoman i use this in my templates `<%= _.slugify(projectName) %>`... now this throw me an error `_ is not defined`... i can't use underscore js in my templates ?

Comment: Then you were using a very very old version of yeoman-generator. It's been changed for more then a year.